# Javascript development - apache write permission

Tags: eclipse, apache, windows-7, permission-denied

I am developing a web site with extjs and my files are in htdocs folder. (Windows 7) 
In eclipse, my workspace will be the htdocs so with this and code modifications, after refresh browser, i see the last source code modifications. This is my idea to development my website.

My problem is when i choose htdocs as my workspace, eclipse can't create .project file. How i can give full acess to write in this folder?

thanks

Comment: What does this problem have to do with Javascript?

Comment: Nothing.. the problem is only with permissions!!

Comment: I have resolved my problem. I give full acess at htdocs for my user and now i don't need the admnistrator permissions